# CTP - check for value inside objects

Tags: terms

I have registered a CTP which can add a new plant and user can tick which months it can be planted (february, march and april for example).
Now, I need to display it on the page but with all months listed starting from the first one.
For example january: no, february: yes, march: yes, april: yes.. december: no.

The problem I am facing is that with `get_the_terms` i get an array with many objects, and I am not sure how to check if value (in any of the objects) is equal to the name of the month.

```
$months = array('january', 'february', 'march'....);
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'myctp' );
foreach($months as $month) {
    foreach($terms as $term){
        if($month== $term->slug)
            echo 'yes';
        else 
            echo 'no';
    }
}
```

This doesn't work good because of the nested foreach loop, it will double/triple... data for each month if more terms are present.

Comment: Can you give var_dump output of `$terms` variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for two loops. Just iterate over the terms and use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    if ( in_array( $term->slug, $months ) {
        echo 'yes';
    else 
        echo 'no';
    }
}
```